# Fastest SD card for Pentax K-01?

Tags: pentax, sdcard, sdhc, sdxc

What SD card type and brand would be the fastest and most reliable for a Pentax K-01 DSLR camera?

Comment: We can't possibly have a question like this for every camera model in existence, _particularly_ when the answers end up being general anyway.

Comment: According to this PentaxForums page, the max write speed of the K-01 is 25 MB/s.  This question shouldn't be marked as duplicate IMHO.  There are answers to these questions, it's just a matter of digging up the information.

https://www.pentaxforums.com/articles/photo-articles/comprehensive-sd-card-guide.html

Answer (score 0):

For speed, you can check out [this website](https://www.sdcard.org/developers/overview/speed_class/) that details what the different symbols and ratings mean. As far as reliability, that comes down to brand reputation with some of the most popular being Lexar and SanDisk. Reading the reviews and knowing that the cheapest option (barring some kind of one-day sale) is probably not the best quality.

These qualities will be independent of the type of equipment you are using/nobody does testing to determine if what's fastest on this device is also what's fastest on that device. To my knowledge it's not possible to test the speed on the device itself and what most people do is test it using software on their computer and assume those results will correlate with what they get on their camera.

The only remotely relevant exception I can think of is that [with the Canon 5DIII, using an SD card limits the CF card to SD speeds](http://www.borrowlenses.com/blog/2013/01/tip-optimize-canon-5d-markiii-write-speeds-avoid-sd-cards/).

Comment: The other Canon models with dual slots (1 CF and 1 SD) do the same thing because the SD slot on those cameras is not UHS-1 compliant. The Canon models with only an SD slot are UHS-1 compliant, though.